# Laravel with Pheanstalkd, Beanstalkd and Supervisor - proper installation

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd

I had install Laravel on Centos 6 with the package Pheanstalkd:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.*",
"pda/pheanstalk": "~2.1"
```

My Laravel queue config file is:

```
return array(
     'default' => 'beanstalkd',
     'connections' => array(
             'beanstalkd' => array(
                  'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
                  'host'   => 'localhost',
                  'queue'  => 'default',
                  'ttr'    => 60,
             ),
             ...

     ),
);
```

Beanstalked has been installed and started and Supervisor had been configured with the following:

```
[program:website]
command=php artisan queue:listen --env=production
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
priority=999
autorestart=true
directory=/var/www/html/
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/app/storage/logs/website_supervisord.log
numprocs=5
numprocs_start=5
startsecs=0
autostart=true
redirect_stderr=true

[program:testing]
command=php artisan queue:listen --env=production
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
priority=999
autorestart=true
directory=/var/www/html/
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/app/storage/logs/testing_supervisord.log
numprocs=5
numprocs_start=5
startsecs=0
autostart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

**website and testing group added and working**

The queue "default" is the one that executes my jobs and i need multiple queues to work in the application ( like my website and testing programs created in supervisor ) .
I had tried:

```
Queue::push('TheBigTest', array('message' => $message), 'website');
```

but with no luck :(

For more details beside the call the class is as follows:

```
<?php

class TheBigTest {

    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        if ($job->attempts() >= 0){
            $job->delete();
        }
        $nr = 1000;
        for ($i=0;$i<=$nr;$i++){
            $newDummy = new Dummy;
            $newDummy->nr = $i;
            $newDummy->other = $i*32;
            $newDummy->save();
        }
        $debug = new Debug;        
        $test = $job->getPheanstalk()->stats();
        $debug->job_execution           = $test["rusage-stime"];
        $debug->job_time                = $test["rusage-utime"];
        $debug->pid                     = $test["pid"];
        $debug->uptime                  = $test["uptime"];
        $debug->job_id                  = $test["id"];
        $debug->max_job_size            = $test["max-job-size"];
        $debug->current_tubes           = $test["current-tubes"];
        $debug->current_connections     = $test["current-connections"];
        $debug->current_workers         = $test["current-workers"];
        $debug->current_waiting         = $test["current-waiting"];
        $debug->total_connections       = $test["total-connections"];
        $debug->total_jobs              = $test["total-jobs"];
        $debug->job_timeouts            = $test["job-timeouts"];
        $debug->debug                   = json_encode($job->getPheanstalk()->listTubeUsed());
        $debug->save();
    }
}
```

Other configuration than this hasn't been done and i don't know how to run on other queues.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to `Queue::push`, from my reading of the docs, appears to be a queue-name (otherwise it will use the name set in the connection, here, `default`). So you've put it into the tube `website`, but are not reading from that queue.  If you show the list of all tubes that are in use (use the command `list-tubes` directly in telnet, or the Laravel Queues library equivalent), you'll see the additional tube names that have jobs in them (besides 'default').